# Issue in generating react js first project

Tags: reactjs, project, create-react-app

I'm trying to generate react project but command prompt freezes and shows no progress in the middle
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UPmR.png)

Tried several times by re opening but did not find result.

Comment: what's your node and npm version?

Comment: node : 12.13.0,npm: 6.13.6

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that npx is downloading packages needed to run *create-react-app* and that is why you experience lag.

Possible solutions:

- Make sure you have enough space on you computer, RAM memory, hard disk memory.
- Wait a bit longer untill all packaged are installed.
- If that doesn't help, try installing *create-react-app* globally `npm i -g create-react-app` and run it as regular npm command: `create-react-app project-name`
- If that still doesnt help, i suggest installing another command terminal, like ConEmu (https://conemu.github.io/) which supports install animation (progress bars and stuff).

Good luck.

Comment: I tried on gitbash , but not working.Last lines are "34 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities". and then nothing happens. @Eugenijus S

Comment: you can downgrade to previous NPM version, where there is no funding. I use Node (v10.15.3) with NPM version 6.9.0 and there is no `npm fund` in it. I think the command you need is something like this: `npm install -g npm@6.9.0`. Once downgraded, try `npm i -g create-react-app` and then run `create-react-app project-name`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by updating npm to latest version
Try updating npm if available by command:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

and try cleaning npm cache

```
npm cache clean
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache.html

Comment: Tried but no result.Screen stops after lines "34 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details found 0 vulnerabilities".